# Error reading 'Cannot read property 'x' of undefined' in HTML5 Canvas code

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, onclick

I am having a problem with my JavaScript code. Since I made it so that you could delete shapes from the canvas an error is appearing when I try adding additional shapes to the canvas. The error reads: 'Cannot read property 'x' of undefined'. When the error appears, it quotes line 116 of the code, which reads: 'var dx = tmpRingB.x - tmpRing.x;'. I need to make it so this error does not appear. The code is as below.

```
var shapeObj = function (counter, context, canvas, settingsBox) {
    //Where sound info goes (freq, vol, amp, adsr etc)
    this.id = "shape"+counter;
    this.ctx = context;
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.sBox = settingsBox;

    this.audioProperties = {
        duration: Math.random()*1-0.1,
        frequency: Math.random()*44000-220
    }

    this.x = Math.random()*this.ctx.canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random()*this.ctx.canvas.height;
    this.radius = 40;
    this.vx = Math.random()*6-3;
    this.vy = Math.random()*6-3;

    this.draw = function () {
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.stroke();
    }

    this.clickTest = function (e) {
        var canvasOffset = this.canvas.offset();
        var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left);
        var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);         
        var dX = this.x-canvasX;
        var dY = this.y-canvasY;
        var distance = Math.sqrt((dX*dX)+(dY*dY));
        if (distance <= this.radius) {
            this.manageClick();
        } 
    };

    this.manageClick = function(){
        alert('this is ' + this.id);
        this.sBox.populate(this.audioProperties, this);
        this.radius -= 10;
    }

    this.update = function(newProps){
        // repopulate the shapes with new settings
    }
}

var settingsBox = function (){
    this.populate = function(props, obj){
        for (a in props){
            alert(props[a]);    
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

    var canvasWidth = canvas.width();
    var canvasHeight = canvas.height();

    $(window).resize(resizeCanvas);

    function resizeCanvas() {
        canvas.attr("width", $(window).get(0).innerWidth - 2);
        canvas.attr("height", $(window).get(0).innerHeight - 124);  
        canvasWidth = canvas.width();
        canvasHeight = canvas.height();
    };

    resizeCanvas();

    canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }

    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;

    var playAnimation = true;

    $(canvas).click(function(e) {
        for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            objects[i].clickTest(e);
        }
    });

    objects = [];

    sBox = new settingsBox();

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var ring = new shapeObj(i, ctx, canvas, sBox);
        objects[i] = ring;  
        objects[i].draw();
    }

    $("#button4").click(function() {
        var ring = new shapeObj(i, ctx, canvas, sBox);
        objects[i] = ring;  
        objects[i++].draw();
        playSoundA();
    });

    function animate() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        deadObjects = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            var tmpRing = objects[i];

            for (var j = i+1; j < objects.length; j++) {
                var tmpRingB = objects[j];

                var dx = tmpRingB.x - tmpRing.x;
                var dy = tmpRingB.y - tmpRing.y;

                var dist = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

                if(dist < tmpRing.radius + tmpRingB.radius) {
                    playSound();

                    //Put collision animations here!!!

                    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                    var sine = Math.sin(angle);
                    var cosine = Math.cos(angle);

                    var x = 0;
                    var y = 0;

                    var xb = dx * cosine + dy * sine;
                    var yb = dy * cosine - dx * sine;

                    var vx = tmpRing.vx * cosine + tmpRing.vy * sine;
                    var vy = tmpRing.vy * cosine - tmpRing.vx * sine;

                    var vxb = tmpRingB.vx * cosine + tmpRingB.vy * sine;
                    var vyb = tmpRingB.vy * cosine - tmpRingB.vx * sine;

                    vx *= -1;
                    vxb *= -1;

                    xb = x + (tmpRing.radius + tmpRingB.radius);

                    tmpRing.x = tmpRing.x + (x * cosine - y * sine);
                    tmpRing.y = tmpRing.y + (y * cosine + x * sine);

                    tmpRingB.x = tmpRing.x + (xb * cosine - yb * sine);
                    tmpRingB.y = tmpRing.y + (yb * cosine + xb * sine);

                    tmpRing.vx = vx * cosine - vy * sine;
                    tmpRing.vy = vy * cosine + vx * sine;

                    tmpRingB.vx = vxb * cosine - vyb * sine;
                    tmpRingB.vy = vyb * cosine + vxb * sine;

                    tmpRing.loop = true;
                };
            };

            tmpRing.x += tmpRing.vx;
            tmpRing.y += tmpRing.vy;

            if (tmpRing.x - tmpRing.radius < 0) {
                playSound();
                tmpRing.x = tmpRing.radius;
                tmpRing.vx *= -1;
            } else if (tmpRing.x + tmpRing.radius > ctx.canvas.width) {
                playSound();
                tmpRing.x = ctx.canvas.width - tmpRing.radius;
                tmpRing.vx *= -1;   
            };

            if (tmpRing.y - tmpRing.radius < 0) {
                playSound();
                tmpRing.y = tmpRing.radius;
                tmpRing.vy *= -1;
            } else if (tmpRing.y + tmpRing.radius > ctx.canvas.height) {
                playSound();
                tmpRing.y = ctx.canvas.height - tmpRing.radius;
                tmpRing.vy *= -1;   
            };

            if(tmpRing.radius <= 0) {
                deadObjects.push(tmpRing);  
            }

            objects[i].draw();
        };

        if (deadObjects.length > 0) {
            for (var d = 0; d < deadObjects.length; d++) {
                var tmpDeadObject = deadObjects[d];
                objects.splice(objects.indexOf(tmpDeadObject), 1);
            }
        }

        if(playAnimation) {
            setTimeout(animate, 33);    
        };
    };

    animate();    
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Code works for me (except `playSound`, which is not defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is undefined because you've deleted it. A simple solution is to check to see if the object is still defined.

insert the following line just before the line with the error.
    if(!(tmpRingB && tmpRing)) continue;

a better solution is to clean house on your array when you delete it.

Comment: how would I clean house on my array?